# How to indicate whitespaces while reading from a .txt file

Tags: c#, winforms, readfile

I have a simple .txt file with X,Y-values in it. It is structured like this:

```
-25.7754  35.87

-22.1233  32.16

-20.361   30.75
```

etc.

I am able to read single lines or the whole text to the end, with objstream.ReadToEnd(); & objstream.ReadLine().
But here's my question how could I indicate when the String after the first value ends so I can save/parse it to float & proceed reading the value of the next string?

Here is the read functionality I have so far :)

```
StreamReader objStream = new StreamReader("C:blablabla\\Text.asc");
            textBox1.Text = objStream.ReadLine();
```

Thanks in advance,

BC++

Comment: I'd suggest reading a line into a string and then splitting on whitespace.

Comment: What is delimiter for values, is delimiter the same for all lines?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [String.split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

As requested, an example :

```
string s = "there is a cat";
//
// Split string on spaces.
// ... This will separate all the words.
//
string[] words = s.Split(' ');
foreach (string word in words)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

The output is :

```
there
is
a
cat
```

Comment: Can you give an example so your question would be more useful?

Comment: I added an example as requested :)

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7h14879.aspx) methods:

```
var line1 = objStream.ReadLine();
var lineParts = line1.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
textBox1.Text = lineParts[0];
textBox2.Text = lineParts[1];
```

Note the use of an overload that uses `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` - the means that if you have multiple spaces in succession, the result will not contain empty entries.

Comment: Argument '2': cannot convert from 'System.StringSplitOptions' to 'char'

Answer (score 1):

If you really mean white-space and not space then you have to go this way:

```
string line = "-25.7754  35.87";
string[] values = line.Split(new char[] { }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

The difference from the other answers in the splitting character. If this not defined then white-space characters are assumed to be the delimiters. In other words you will get the same result for

```
string line = "-25.7754\t35.87"; // tab instead of spaces.
```

You will have the flexibility to split correctly fixed length or tab delimited lines using the same code.